# Group by year only from field which is in Java Date class format in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, epoch

I am working in PostgreSQL, I have table name my_table schema

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
  my_table_id character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  bar_id character varying(50),
  beer_id character varying(50),
  status_id character varying(50),

  updated_at bigint,

  CONSTRAINT my_table_id PRIMARY KEY (craft_bar_beer_id ),
  CONSTRAINT my_table_bar_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (bar_id)
      REFERENCES table_bar (bar_id) MATCH Unknown
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT beer_status_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (status_id)
      REFERENCES status (status_id) MATCH Unknown
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT beer_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (beer_id)
      REFERENCES beer (beer_id) MATCH Unknown
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

Now the output is count of beer_id which are having status as '1' and '2' and group by date (here suppose the year 2016 is provided or for last 10 years the record should get displayed)

```
count(beer_id)   status     year
4                  1        2014
5                  1        2015
3                  2        2014
6                  2        2016
```

But here the field `updated_at` is a `bigint` which is time in milliseconds derived from a Java `Date` object:

```
Date dateValue = null;
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
dateValue = formatter.parse(dateStr);
return dateValue.getTime();
```

Query I tried:

```
SELECT count(cbeer.beer_id) AS beers, cbeer.status_id AS Status
FROM my_table cbeer
INNER JOIN bar cb ON cb.bar_id = cbeer.bar_id
WHERE status_id IN ('1','2')
GROUP BY cbeer.status_id;
```

OUTPUT:

```
beers Status
5      1
1      2
```

How to query to get the date wise records too when date is in long and I want it to group by it by last 10 years. And if year provided for ex: 2015, group by it 2015 and get the month related records for that year.

Comment: Storing a timestamp as a long was not such a good idea to begin with (you now see why). But you can convert a unix epoch value to a timestamp using `to_timestamp()`. See the manual for details http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

Comment: You say time is expressed in milli-seconds and stored in a `long`. Can you show us a sample of this? And are you sure it is milli-seconds and not seconds?

Comment: @Patrick Yes i have converted date in string to time in milliseconds and store it in  datatype bigint. what sample you want me to show you?

Comment: Can you show an example of how you convert this string to a `bigint`? The reason is that "date" (+ time, presumably) stored in a `bigint` requires some point of reference. What date + time is represented by a value of 0? The old standard in PostgreSQL is to store a `timestamp` in bigint format with the Unix default 0 point **in seconds**. Hence my questions.

Comment: Date dateValue = null;SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
  formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    dateValue = formatter.parse(dateStr);
    
  return dateValue.getTime();

Answer (score 2):

The Java `Date.getTime()` function returns the object as a `long` in milliseconds since 1 January 1970. Luckily this is the same epoch that PostgreSQL uses so you can simply divide the value by 1,000 and convert to a `timestamp` to have full access to the PostgreSQL date and time functions:

```
to_timestamp(updated_at / 1000.)
```

Now your queries. For the last 10 years:

```
SELECT count(cbeer.beer_id) AS beers,
       cbeer.status_id AS Status,
       extract('year' from to_timestamp(updated_at / 1000.)) AS year
FROM my_table cbeer
INNER JOIN bar cb ON cb.bar_id = cbeer.bar_id
WHERE status_id IN ('1','2')
  AND extract('year' from to_timestamp(updated_at / 1000.)) > 2005
GROUP BY 2, 3
ORDER BY 2, 3, 1;
```

For the month:

```
SELECT count(cbeer.beer_id) AS beers,
       cbeer.status_id AS Status,
       extract('month' from to_timestamp(updated_at / 1000.)) AS month
FROM my_table cbeer
INNER JOIN bar cb ON cb.bar_id = cbeer.bar_id
WHERE status_id IN ('1','2')
  AND extract('year' from to_timestamp(updated_at / 1000.)) = 2015
GROUP BY 2, 3
ORDER BY 2, 3, 1;
```

Comment: You also need to find the schema designer and "educate" them. Firmly. Storing a date in a bigint, ugh.

Comment: What @CraigRinger so passionately was trying to say is: Don't store Java internal format in a database. Instead use something like `PreparedStatement.setDate()` so that you get data that the DBMS understands and can manipulate.